# List for the 2012 Summer Games, each sports name and the number of disciplines for that sport in which competitions were held?

Tags: oracle

List for the 2012 Summer Games, each sports name and the number of disciplines for that sport  in which competitions were held?

here's what I got but it return with an ambiguous answer. what am I doing wrong? Help please..

```
SELECT
    sport_name as "Sport Name",
    COUNT(discipline_code) as "Number of Disciplines"
FROM
    GAMES.SPORT,
    GAMES.GAMESDISCIPLINE,
    GAMES.SUMMERGAMES
WHERE
    sg_year = 2012
GROUP BY
    sport_name;
```

Comment: There appear to be no table joins. You'll end up with a cartesian join which would join every row in one table with every row in another table.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have any [joins](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/queries006.htm) between the three tables, so you'll get a cartesian product. Try switching to ANSI join syntax to make this clearer. You'll need to put in the real column names that form the joins between the tables, I'm just guessing here:

```
SELECT
    s.sport_name as "Sport Name",
    COUNT(gs.discipline_code) as "Number of Disciplines"
FROM GAMES.SUMMERGAMES sg
JOIN GAMES.GAMESDISCIPLINE gd ON gd.games_id = sg.games_id
JOIN GAMES.SPORT s ON s.discipline_id = gd.discipline_id
WHERE
    sg.sg_year = 2012
GROUP BY
    s.sport_name;
```